# Convert text to tag in Tagify

Tags: javascript, jquery, tagify

I would like to know how it is possible by code to convert a text to a tag. Suppose we have the following text:

```
[[{"value":2,"text":"Petrol Man","title":"Petrol Man","prefix":"@"}]]
```

how do I, via code convert it to the tagify classic graphical display?

EDIT:

I would convert this text     `[[{"value":2,"text":"Petrol Man","title":"Petrol Man","prefix":"@"}]]` to:

[image]

Comment: Can you put the cod you want?

Comment: Can you include the src= for the tagify plugin/code that you're using please?   The [tag:tagify] [SO wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tagify/info) is a little underdetailed, as would probably be a generic *tagify* rather than whichever specific plugin you are using.

Comment: <script src="../tagify.js"></script>
        <script src="../tagify.polyfills.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../tagify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: ... and... where did you download `tagify.js` from in the first place?  Maybe there's a source in the first few lines of tagify.js

Comment: * Tagify (v 4.12.0) - tags input component
 * By Yair Even-Or
 * https://github.com/yairEO/tagify

Comment: Is your "text" actually text? as in var x = '[[{"value":2... }]]"`

Comment: yes it is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the assumptions:

> tagify v4.12.0 from https://github.com/yairEO/tagify
>
> provided data is a JSON string containing a nested array `[[{..}]]`

The tagify page has an example of adding new tags:

```
tagify.addTags(["banana", "orange", "apple"])
```

so you need to convert your json-string to an array of text values.

Use `JSON.parse` to convert to an object then `data[0].map(` to read each value out of the inner array - as the outer array (in the sample at least) is always a single dimension, you need `data[0]` to get to the inner array.

Put together:

```js
var tagify = new Tagify(document.getElementById("tags"));

//tagify.addTags(["banana", "orange", "apple"])

// added a second example in the inner array otherwise it's just `data[0][0].title`
var txt = '[[{"value":2,"text":"Petrol Man","title":"Petrol Man","prefix":"@"}, {"text":"Diesel Woman"}]]';
var data = JSON.parse(txt);
var newTags = data[0].map(t => t.text);

tagify.addTags(newTags);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@yaireo/tagify"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@yaireo/tagify/dist/tagify.polyfills.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@yaireo/tagify/dist/tagify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<input id='tags'>
```

Unfortunately, the plugin uses `localStorage` without checking if it's available - and SO doesn't allow this, so no working snippet above, but here's a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/50n7ckLe/